# How can I convert Jenkins pipeline to Github using docker container?

Tags: github, jenkins, pipeline, action

How do I convert CD/CI Jenkins pipeline to Github CD/CI actions using docker container?

I tried converting Jenkins file to match Github actions but the dockerfile is causing multiple errors below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O17XF.png)

Here is the Dockerfile code that I used below. This is the code causing the error from line 70.

```
# PHP dependencies (replace this with an image prolly)
#
FROM composer:1.8.4 as composer

WORKDIR /var/www

# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git libzip-dev zip  && \
#     docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip && \
#     docker-php-ext-install zip && \
#     curl -o /tmp/composer-setup.php https://getcomposer.org/installer && \
#     curl -o /tmp/composer-setup.sig https://composer.github.io/installer.sig && \
#     # Make sure we're installing what we think we're installing!
#     php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('/tmp/composer-setup.php')) !== trim(file_get_contents('/tmp/composer-setup.sig'))) { unlink('/tmp/composer-setup.php'); echo 'Invalid installer' . PHP_EOL; exit(1); }" && \
#     php /tmp/composer-setup.php --no-ansi --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --snapshot && \
#     rm -f /tmp/composer-setup.* && \
#     mkdir /var/www/.composer && \
#     chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

# RUN php -v


# RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer && \
    # mkdir /var/www/.composer && \
    # chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
    # chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.composer
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data .

USER www-data

COPY composer.json composer.json
RUN composer install \
    # --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist \
    --no-autoloader



# We want our app stuff to be autoloaded by composer,
# so we need to copy it in
COPY app app
RUN ls

#
# Node dependencies
#
FROM node:14-alpine as node

RUN apk update && apk add git

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY package.json package.json

RUN npm install

#
# FPM runner
#
FROM php:5.6-fpm

# RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /var/www


RUN ls -la && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 libzip-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


COPY --from=node /var/www/node_modules node_modules
COPY --from=composer /var/www/vendor vendor
COPY . .

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data app/storage && \
    chmod -R 775 app/storage && \
    php artisan clear-compiled && \
    php artisan optimize 

RUN php -v

USER www-data`
```

Comment: Try narrowing down which of the run commands is causing the failure. Once you figure that out, you can fix that specific command and move forward.

Comment: Also if possible, post the whole Dockerfile you are using as text to the question, it might give more hints on why this happens.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.